# Python Django NoReverseMatch Template

Tags: python, django, url, django-templates

I configured the path and made the template but when I try to run server it gives

NoReverseMatch at /password-reset/
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/password-reset/
Django Version: 3.0.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
error. 
My  urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [



    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name= 'register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name = 'users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name = 'users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset.html'),
         name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/',
```

auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'),
         name='password_reset_done '),
    path('password-reset-confirm///',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'),
         name='password_reset_confirm '),

```
    path('', include('blog.urls'))
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


and my template 
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class = "content section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class= "form-group">
                <legend class = "border-bottom mb-4">Reset Password</legend>
                {{form|crispy}}
            </fieldset>
            <div class = "form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type ="submit"> Reset Password </button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>


{% endblock content %}
```

Could you please tell me what is wrong with my project? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you got a space in the name of `'password_reset_confirm '`

```
'password_reset_confirm '
                       ^
```

Not sure how django well django handles that. If that is not the issue, please post the code where you reverse-call the URL in the template (where the {% url ... %} template tag is or possibly from your view where you configured your e.g. success URL.